# Struct Inclusion/Implementation Help Needed (pt 2) C++

Tags: c++, struct, header-files, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to adapt a bit of code for a doubly-linked list to be included and used in my mysh.cpp file, and I'm getting

```
mysh.cpp:88: error: no matching function for call to ‘readcommand::initialize(linked_list*)’
readcommand.h:32: note: candidates are: static void readcommand::initialize(readcommand::linked_list*)
mysh.cpp:100: error: no matching function for call to ‘readcommand::add(linked_list*, char*&)’
readcommand.h:34: note: candidates are: static void readcommand::add(readcommand::linked_list*, char*)
mysh.cpp:114: error: no matching function for call to ‘readcommand::traverse(linked_list*, void(char*))’
readcommand.h:38: note: candidates are: static void readcommand::traverse(readcommand::linked_list*, void (*)(char*))
```

and similar errors for the add(linked_list*, char*) and traverse(linked_list*, void (*callback) (char *)) functions in my readcommand.cpp file (the header is included in mysh.cpp

---

I had a problem a few days ago involving an earlier step in getting my header file to work with mysh.cpp ([Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049632/struct-inclusion-implementation-help-needed-c)), and have since solved that by moving the struct definitions to the top of the readcommand.h file. Now I'm stuck with this error, and not sure where to go next.

Here are the relevant portions of the files:

**readcommand.cpp**

```
static void initialize (linked_list *list) {
  list->first = 0;
  list->last = 0;
}

static void add (linked_list *list, char *word) {
  node *nodeX;

  nodeX = talloc();

  if (! nodeX) {
    fprintf (stderr, "allocation failure\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  nodeX->word = word;

  if (list->last) {
    list->last->next = nodeX;
    nodeX->prev = list->last;
    list->last = nodeX;
  }
  else {
    list->first = nodeX;
    list->last = nodeX;
  }
}
```

**readcommand.h**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

struct node {
  const char *word;
  node *prev;
  node *next;
};

struct linked_list {
  node *first;
  node *last;
};

class readcommand {

  public:

  // Struct Definitions    
  typedef node node_t;
  typedef linked_list linked_list_t;

  // Creation
  static void initialize (linked_list *list);
  node *talloc ();
  static void add (linked_list *list, char *word);

  // Modification and Traversal
  static void del_list (linked_list *list, node *nodeX);
  static void traverse (linked_list *list, void (*callback) (char *));
  static void reverse (linked_list *list, void (*callback) (char *));
  static void traverse_delete (linked_list *list, int (*callback) (char *));
  static void free (linked_list *list);
  static int delete_all (char *word);
  static void print (char *word);

};
```

**mysh.cpp**

```
#include "readcommand.h"

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

  readcommand read;
  linked_list list;
  string input = "";
  read.initialize (& list);

  // Read input string here
  getline (cin, input);
  cout << endl;

  // Parse words individually and add to linked list
  int len = input.length();
  char *str = (char *) input.c_str();
  char *word = strtok (str, " ");

  while (word != NULL) {
    read.add (& list, word);
    word = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }

  read.traverse(& list, read.print);
  printf("\n");

  return (0);
}
```

---

Should I be initializing "linked_list list" in a different way, or does this simply demand another re-arranging of declarations?

Thanks ahead of time for the help.

---

**UPDATE:** With the change mentioned by Stephen Lin, the errors I'm getting are now:

```
mysh.cpp:88: undefined reference to `readcommand::initialize(linked_list*)'
mysh.cpp:100: undefined reference to `readcommand::add(linked_list*, char*)'
mysh.cpp:114: undefined reference to `readcommand::print(char*)'
mysh.cpp:114: undefined reference to `readcommand::traverse(linked_list*, void (*)(char*))'
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** My new error:

```
mysh.cpp:114: error: no matching function for call to ‘readcommand::traverse(linked_list*, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
readcommand.h:35: note: candidates are: void readcommand::traverse(linked_list*, void (*)(char*))
```

**mysh.cpp**

```
read.traverse(& list, read.print);
```

**readcommand.cpp**

```
void readcommand::traverse (linked_list *list, void (*callback) (char *)) {
  node *nodeX;

  for (nodeX = list->first; nodeX; nodeX = nodeX->next) {
    callback ((char *) nodeX->word);
  }
}    

void readcommand::print (char *word) {
  printf ("%s, ", (char *) word);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the lines:

```
// Struct Definitions
struct node;
struct linked_list;
```

You are shadowing the global type definitions of those structs with a new types declared local to class `readcommand`

Also:

```
typedef struct node node_t;
typedef struct linked_list linked_list_t;
```

Is fine as:

```
typedef node node_t;
typedef linked_list linked_list_t;
```

And is preferred in C++, although the former will work too.

EDIT:

Also, your functions are not defined properly, they are defined as global functions rather than member functions:

```
static void initialize (linked_list *list) {
    // ...
}
```

should be

```
static void readcommand::initialize (linked_list *list) {
    // ...
}
```

and similarly for your other definitions. Note that, since it seems like all your functions are `static` (except one?) and you have no member variables, you are not really using the class `readcommand` for anything except a namespace..i.e. you're not using any object-oriented features. That's acceptable, but it doesn't seem to be your intention in this case, because you are instantiating a object of class `readcommand` and calling static function using the dot (`.`) operator on it, which is possible but serves no purpose.

You probably mean to not use `static`, and mean to make `list` a member variable of `readcommand`, but I am not 100% sure. Otherwise, you can just skip creating the object entirely and call everything as `readcommand::initialize(...)`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely cut down on some of the errors, but I'm still having an issue with "undefined reference to X method", which I've added to the end of the question along with updating the code with the changes you suggested.

What is causing this?

Comment: `static void initialize (linked_list *list)` should be `static void readcommand::initialize (linked_list *list)`, etc.

Comment: Ah, it's been so long.  Thanks again.

I've updated each of the functions (removed static and added readcommand::) and now I'm just getting an error when I attempt to call `traverse` , which accepts a linked_list and a callback function (in this case I'm passing it `read.print`).

`mysh.cpp:114: error: no matching function for call to ‘readcommand::traverse(linked_list*, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
readcommand.h:35: note: candidates are: void readcommand::traverse(linked_list*, void (*)(char*))`

I'll add the print function to the question.

Comment: should be `&readcommand::print` (`readcommand::print` if probably acceptable too, but I prefer the former), but actually in this case `print` does need to be `static`. Google for "pointer to function" and "pointer to member function" (although the latter might be a bit too much immediately...)

Comment: Yep, that definitely fixed it.  I had no idea that I was supposed to keep the print function declared as `static void print(char*);` in the header file, but `void readcommand::print (char *word)` in .cpp file.  Been quite some time since my last C++ endeavor.

It's all working perfectly now, so thank you one last time.